# NSDate String Returns nil

Tags: objective-c, string, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm following the code with the debugger and I don't understand why it's returning `nil` instead of a date.

Passing this into it :  `2016-02-12T19:47:29+0000`

```
-(NSString*)formatDate:(NSString*)date {
    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ";

    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
}
```

Comment: try `HH` instead of `hh`

Comment: Like @luk2302 said, use the 24 hour format to create the date, and then set the format again to create the string in 12 hour format.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the same format to convert a string to a date and then back to the same string? Why bother with the conversion?

Comment: Off topic here, but a few coding style suggestions: 1) don't name the parameter date if it's a string. 2) There's no need for the dateString variable at all. Just use the parameter. 3) Don't alloc/init dateFromString. You're just destroying that thing by overwriting it the very next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're just testing conversion by going from string->date->string, or possibly the intention is to produce an equivalent string in a different time zone.

The following will convert an input string describing a date to a string describing that same date in the device's time zone.  A different time zone can be achieved by setting the formatter's timeZone...

```
-(NSString*)formatDate:(NSString*)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";  // this is an RFC3339 date without milliseconds

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    // to convert to a different timezone, try, for example:
    // dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
    return  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: thanks!  works good now
[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";  // this is an RFC3339 date without milliseconds
    
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

Answer (score 0):

The time you are passing is in a 24 hour format, you have to use `HH` for the `NSDateFormatter` to be able to read this. Once you have an `NSDate` created you can then set a new format with 12 hours using `hh`.

Here it is in code.

```
-(NSString*)formatDate:(NSString*)date {

    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ";

    return   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
}
```

Comment: 1) You should always use `a` along with `hh` in a date format. 2) How do you know the OP wants the result to be in that format?

Comment: Well he has a date in a string and getting a string back from this, I am assuming he is trying to take a 24hr time and format it into 12hrs.